# Ошибка сегментирования( segmentation fault)

Tags: c

[image]
Выдаёт ошибку сегментирования в выделенной области

Comment: `scanf` неправильно используете.

Comment: Также, хоть это и не "в выделенной области": массивы в С индексируются с 0, а не 1. У вас там дальше вылет за пределы массива, Также зачем вы написали `x=` и `y=` в формате `scanf`? Также, формат `%li` в вашем `printf` неуместен. Также, что такое `<malloc.h>`?

Comment: @AnT линуховый маллок с плюшками)

Comment: @Andrey: ... нинафиг не нужен в программе на С. А уж тем более - в этой.

Comment: @AnT мало ли тс хотел GFP_KERNEL память потрогать ))))

Comment: @Andrey: Память по координатам `x` и `y` на поверхности линуксового ядра...

Comment: Минус за прикрепление кода картинкой. Пожалуйста, вставляйте код текстом.

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны написать 
scanf(%d", &N);
scanf(%d", &X);